# Add a "Thank you for your order" page that is not directly visitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When the user purchases an item we want to display a thank you page.
Then again we want this page not to be directly visitable.
In other words, if the page was to be /orders/thankyou, the user could directly navigate to it which would be rather ugly and fail aas it would have nothing to show.

how can we show this page only when in context and forbid direct navigation to it?

Comment: you can create partial form for this.. and put the condition in your controller hope it solved ur issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a partial form and append it to the DOM after the purchase event is fired. In the partial view, be sure to add a redirect action if it was accessed without the purchase event firing.

Answer (score 2):

For just displaying short text (and not also e.g. the order data) you could just use a flash notice. For example:

```
redirect_to @page, notice: "Thank you for your order!"
```

Comment: we want to show all order data and other info as well

Answer (score 1):

**Ajax**

Sounds like you'll be best using `ajax`:

```
#app/views/cart/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag cart_order_path, remote: true do |f| %>
   ... (cart form)
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This (obviously very simple) form will send a "remote" (Ajax) form submission to your controller. The reason why this is important is because you will then handle the *response* directly in that page you just sent the *request* from:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:success", "#your_form_id", function(status, data, xhr) {
   $("your_page_div").html(data);
});
```

The trick here will be to render your *thank you* view *without* a layout -

```
#app/controllers/cart_controller.rb
class CartController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, only: :create

   def create
      ... business logic here
      render "thank_you", layout: false
   end
end
```

This will render the view you want without any of the supporting "layout" HTML - giving you the chance to append that to your current view. This means that if you wanted to show the "Thank You" view without letting the user browse to it directly - that's what you'll do

---

**How It Works**

[Ajax (Asynchronous Javascript and XML)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is a javascript technology which basically allows you to send "pseudo requests" to your Rails backend:

[image]

Basically the same as a standard HTTP request, except handled with Javascript, Ajax gives you the ability to create the appearance of "no refresh" functionality in your app. It does this by sending requests on your behalf, through Javascript.

Ajax is typically used for small pieces of functionality on web interfaces - whereby you'll have the ability to send simple requests to the server, gaining a comparable response that you can then work into the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

This is the functionality I have been proposing - whereby you'll be able to send a request to your controller (albeit using the `Rails UJS engine`), to which you'll then receive a response. This response can then be worked into your page, thus providing you with the ability to show the "Thank You" page without the user refreshing.

Comment: in our case we want to redirect away from the order screen as this is done on a SSL secured page on a different host. We want to navigate back to our url.

Comment: Oh okay! Have you tried using `redirect_to`, like `Suomi`'s answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any solution from the following:

Using [ActionDispatch::Flash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html):

```
flash[:notice] = "Thank you for your order!"
redirect_to @page
```

or

```
redirect_to @page, notice: "Thank you for your order!"
```

Using [alert](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp), in `show.js.haml` file (assuming you use action `show` in `orders_controller.rb`):

```
alert("Thank you for your order!");
```

and then add `respond_to :js, only: :show`, and `format.js` in action `show` for `orders_controller.rb`

Comment: flash[:notice] would not work for us because the ordering is taking place on another host. (sorry for not mentioning this). so the user would have to navigate back to our host and would not see the notice. If he would purchase again in the same session he would even see this message on the new host (if shown there) before placing his next purchase order. redirect_to and js would work but we dont want to open new windows that may be suppressed by popup blockers. Though skipping the alert your proposed solution would work for us, we will proceed with Stephen Bagsic's solution.